# VBA - Cut and Paste cells if Column A is Blank

Tags: excel, vba, paste

What I'm trying to do is the following:

Column A

- xx
- yy
- xx
- zz
- (blank)
- (blank)
- (blank)
- xx
- yy
- hh

...for the blank space, there are values in column C "ff, gg, tt", that are horizontally aligned with the blanks, that I need to cut and paste into column A. This applies throughout the table, through maybe 400 lines.

So I want to say:

"If Column A has a blank cell then cut and paste the value of corresponding cell from Column C"

And loop through the document

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if the values are not formulas on the worksheet:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim toprow As Long
toprow = 1 'Change this to whatever the top row is

For i = toprow To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
    Cells(i, 3).Copy Cells(i, 1)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Otherwise you will need to modify the code to pastespecial values

Comment: This worked great, thank you!

I didn't really have anything currently, I was more trying to adjust a cut/paste script I found elsewhere to be the condition of cells being blank, but was definitely not on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple apporoach without code:

1.insert a column A and put auto row numbers 1,2,3...n

2.sort all columns by column B to group all blank spaces in first rows.

3.Copy all column C values to Clumn B in one move.

4. ReSort Columns by column A
5. delete Column A

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on all values in Column A and Column B and you want to avoid the loop you could just `PasteSpecial` and `SkipBlanks`. You wouldn't need to use code, but if you did you'd use:

```
Columns(2).Copy
Columns(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
Columns(2).ClearContents
```